# Sort by date only working for the current page, inside a paged repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to do a sort here to display the latest entries first. I have a repeater control which is bound to a `pagedDataSource`, and my sorting only works for page wise rather than the whole collection itself.

**here is my code behind :**

```
    private int RowCount
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)ViewState["RowCount"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["RowCount"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FetchData(5, 0);                    
        }
        else
        {
            plcPaging.Controls.Clear();
            CreatePagingControl();
        }

    }

    private void FetchData(int take, int pageSize)
    {
        using (krystaladbDataContext db = new krystaladbDataContext())
        {
            var query = from q in db.question_tables

                        .Take(take)
                        .Skip(pageSize)

                        orderby q.QUEST_POSTED_DATE descending
                        select new
                        {


                            QUEST_ID = q.QUEST_ID,
                            QUEST_TEXT = q.QUEST_TEXT,
                            QUEST_POSTED_DATE = q.QUEST_POSTED_DATE,
                            QUEST_USR_ID = q.QUEST_USR_ID,
                            QUEST_LIKES_COUNT = q.QUEST_LIKES_COUNT,
                            QUEST_REPORT_COUNT = q.QUEST_REPORT_COUNT,
                            Count = db.question_tables.Count()

                        };




            PagedDataSource page = new PagedDataSource();
            page.AllowCustomPaging = true;
            page.AllowPaging = true;
            page.DataSource = query;
            page.PageSize = 5;
            QRep.DataSource = page;
            QRep.DataBind();

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                RowCount = query.First().Count;
                CreatePagingControl();

            }
        }
    }

    private void CreatePagingControl()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (RowCount / 5) + 1; i++)
        {
            LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
            lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lbl_Click);
            lnk.ID = "lnkPage" + (i + 1).ToString();
            lnk.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
            plcPaging.Controls.Add(lnk);
            Label spacer = new Label();
            spacer.Text = "&nbsp;";
            plcPaging.Controls.Add(spacer);
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:: included the page control event handler**

```
    void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
        int currentPage = int.Parse(lnk.Text);
        int take = currentPage * 5;
        int skip = currentPage == 1 ? 0 : take - 5;
        FetchData(take, skip);
    }
```

What I want is basically to have the sort work across all the pages rather than for just one page. Please point me in the right direction guys. Thanks

Comment: Can you do orderby before the .Take/.Skip? The way I'm reading it, you are taking your page of records, then sorting it.

Comment: Sam , that cant be done, gives a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the order by before the take.

```
var query = from q in db.question_tables
            orderby q.QUEST_POSTED_DATE descending
            select new
            {
              QUEST_ID = q.QUEST_ID,
              QUEST_TEXT = q.QUEST_TEXT,
              QUEST_POSTED_DATE = q.QUEST_POSTED_DATE,
              QUEST_USR_ID = q.QUEST_USR_ID,
              QUEST_LIKES_COUNT = q.QUEST_LIKES_COUNT,
              QUEST_REPORT_COUNT = q.QUEST_REPORT_COUNT,
              Count = db.question_tables.Count()
             }
             .Take(take)
             .Skip(pageSize);
```

You could alternatively use the linq [.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) method before the `.Take`

Then on the paging control.

```
void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
    int currentPage = int.Parse(lnk.Text);
    int take = page.PageSize;
    int skip = page.PageSize * (currentPage - 1); 
    FetchData(take, skip);
}
```

Comment: thanks , but this gives the same set of data items on every page.

Comment: You only call FetchData(5,0) in the page load with 5,0 which will get the first 5 records as none are skipped. You need to call it when some pages and pass in new parameters based on the page they are on.

Comment: i have edited the question to include the paged control event handler. can u check again . thanks

Comment: I dnt think thats where the problem is. The problem is that the query is executed AND sorted for every page load. I need the query to be full and one time . i think that would solve the problem. any idea how i can do that ? thanks

Comment: I used the linq OrderBy and that solves the problem. Thanks for your help.

.OrderByDescending(q => q.QUEST_POSTED_DATE.Date)

Comment: that too is a nice concept @benni, but i think what I am doing here is more efficient. It does fetch only the relevent portion on postbacks and extracts data in a one way process. just my opinion though. thanks